# Faster method for exporting embedded data

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource, copying

For some reasons, i'm using the method described here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205174253/http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx)

It starts off from the first byte of the embedded file and goes through 4.234.925 bytes one by one! It takes approximately 40 seconds to finish.

Is there any other methods for copying an embedded file to the hard-disk? (I maybe wrong here but i think the embedded file is read from the memory)

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting! I have tried to do this before from C#, by copying an embedded resource (which was a native unmanaged DLL) and load it into the process's space by memory mapping the resource and making the memory mapped file executable, and then invoke a function on it which failed.. am still wrestling on that challenge myself! Why are you not using the 'WriteFile' function which can take an arbitary buffer of a certain size and write it out in one swell foop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know the location and size of the embedded exe , then you can do it in one write.

```
LPBYTE pbExtract; // the pointer to the data to extract
UINT   cbExtract; // the size of the data to extract.

HANDLE hf;
hf = CreateFile("filename.exe",          // file name
                GENERIC_WRITE,           // open for writing 
                0,                       // no share
                NULL,                    // no security 
                CREATE_ALWAYS,           // overwrite existing
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,   // normal file 
                NULL);                   // no template 

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hf)
{
   DWORD cbWrote;
   WriteFile(hf, pbExtract, cbExtract, &cbWrote, NULL);
   CloseHandle(hf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the man says, write more of the file (or the whole thing) per WriteFile call. A WriteFile call per byte is going to be ridiculously slow yes.